# How do I get PHP to display a user picture if you have one within a blog post?

Tags: php

I have a script that can disply user pictures but I want to have it now so if you don't have a picture it displays a default one.

**CODE**

```
if (file_exists($displayuserimage)) {
    $displayuserimage =  '<img src="upic/'. $posts['userid'].'.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" border="2"  />';
} else {
    $displayuserimage =  '<img src="upic/default.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" border="2"/>'; 
}
```

That's what im guessing, but this is the working script, that shows images if you have one:

```
$displayuserimage = '<img src="upic/'. $posts['userid'].'.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" border="2"/>';
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Edited to specify question

Comment: It doesn't work, it makes all posts show the default image and I get an error saying 'Undefined variable' on the 'if' statement line

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` is checking a variable,`$displayuserimage`, which has not been defined before. To check if your image exists, that `if` may look like

```
if (file_exists("upic/". $posts['userid'].".jpg")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's file_exists() function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

```
$image="/path/on/local/server/to/image/icon.png";
$http_image="http://whatever.com/url/to/image";

if(file_exists($image))
{
  echo "<img src=\"$http_image\"/>\n";
}
else
{
  echo "<img src=\"uploads/$username/noprofile.png\"/>\n";
}
```

Use the same scenario if you are calling user images from Database too. Replace the

```
echo "<img src=\"$http_image\"/>\n";
```

with your row from the Database which contains your user's profile image. Example:

> echo $rows['user_image'];